# populating dropdown lists from linq to sql statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

i have two different dropdown lists and each have a select statement to return proper information. Running into a few issues:

- what format should i properly return the results from select statement as?
- do i control the select statement of the second dropdown list based on the id from the selected item in the first dropdown list.

**Service layer:
1st dropdown list**

```
public IEnumerable<ContentVw> GetSections()
        {
            using (var db = my connection info)
            {
                var sections = (from e in db.Table1
    join re in db.RootTables re
    on e.ID equals re.Table1ID
    where re.ChairID == 1
    select new { e.DisplayName, e.ID, e.GUID };
                return sections;
            }
        }
```

**error:** cannot convert IQueryable anonymous to ...ContentVw

**2nd dropdownList**

```
public IEnumerable<ContentVw> GetContent(int itemId) //itemId = first dropdown list selection
        {
            using (var db = my connection info)
            {
                var content = (from e in db.Table1 join em in db.TableToTableMaps on e.ID equals em.KnowsTableID where em.TableID == itemId select new { e.DisplayName, e.ID, e.GUID });
            }
        }
```

**ContentVw:**

```
public partial class ContentVw
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Guid GUID { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ContentManage()
        {
            var _sections = new ContentService().GetSections().ToList();
            ViewBag.SectionsDropdown = _sections;
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning an anonymous object instead of your `ContentVw`.

```
public IEnumerable<ContentVw> GetSections()
{
    using (var db = my connection info)
    {
        var sections = from e in db.Table1
                       join re in db.RootTables re
                       on e.ID equals re.Table1ID
                       where re.ChairID == 1
                       select new ContentVw
                           {
                               Name = e.DisplayName,
                               Id = e.ID,
                               GUID = e.GUID
                           };

        return sections;
    }
}

public IEnumerable<ContentVw> GetContent(int itemId) //itemId = first dropdown list selection
{
    using (var db = my connection info)
    {
        var content = (from e in db.Table1
                       join em in db.TableToTableMaps
                       on e.ID equals em.KnowsTableID
                       where em.TableID == itemId
                       select new ContentVw
                           {
                               Name = e.DisplayName,
                               Id = e.ID,
                               GUID = e.GUID
                           });

        return content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful your code returns IQueriable object. It will make request to DB each time you will use returned object.

Comment: He could just append the `ToList` when he is actually returning the results: `var results = GetContent(<id>).ToList()`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
    public IEnumerable<ContentVw> GetSections()
    {
        using (var db = my connection info)
        {
            return (from e in db.Table1
                            join re in db.RootTables re
                            on e.ID equals re.Table1ID
                            where re.ChairID == 1                                
                            select new ContentVw { Name = e.DisplayName, // here you get ContentVw  objects
                                                   Id = e.ID,
                                                   GUID = e.GUID }).ToList();

        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ContentManage()
        {
            var _sections = new ContentService().GetSections();
            // ViewBag.SectionsDropdown = _sections; // i prefare to pass data im model
            return View(_sections);
        }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<ContentVw>

@{ // populate list of <SelectListItem> for helper
   var listItems = Model.Select(x => new SelectListItem {
        Text = Name,
        Value = Id.ToString()
   }).ToList();
}

@Html.DropDownList("List", listItems)
```

Comment: Thanks i am implementing this now. How can i get my results that i got  in my service layer into my controller so i will be able to display it in dropdown list in my view page?

Comment: You can pass data to view with model property or with ViewBag/Viewdata property.

Comment: I updated my controller above and when i debut i see the results i want in _sections. So in my view do i do something like this: `@Html.DropDownList(SectionsDropDown);`

Comment: i am getting a compile error on `x=> new SelectListItem` stating cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operations without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type.